# Split an array in 20-item parts and the leftover to vanillaJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, algorithm, react-hooks

I need to get such results from my function:

```
if arr.length == 65
then the splittedarr will be : [[obj 1, obj 2, obj 3.... obj 4 ... obj 20], [obj 21 .. obj 40], 
[obj 41 ... obj 65]]
```

In vanillaJS yet this will be set to react hook's variable, and this is my code

```
useEffect(() => {
    setSplitted([]);
    const foundCopy = found.slice();
    let i = 0;
    if(!found[i + 20]) {
      console.log("I", i)
      let mutablecopy = foundCopy.slice();
      return setSplitted(curr => [...curr, mutablecopy.splice(i, found.length - i)])
    }
    while(foundCopy[i + 20]) {
      console.log("I", i)
      let mutablecopy = foundCopy.slice();
      console.log(mutablecopy)
      setSplitted(curr => [...curr, mutablecopy.splice(i, i + 20)]);
      i += 20;
    }
    
  }, [found]);
```

My current code gives me two same arrays 20 items per each :( Please help me making me out how to implement it, it would be good with pseudocode too! Thank you!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to chunk your input into groups of 20, but if there is not enough for a final full group to make the last one larger.

This recursive version should do it:

```js
const chunk = (n) => (xs) =>
  xs .length <= 2 * n ? [[...xs]] : [xs.slice(0, n), ... chunk (n) (xs .slice (n))]

const input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65]

console .log (chunk(20) (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We simply test whether we have more than enough items for a single group.  If we do, we take the first `n` of them and combine that with the result of calling again with the same `n` for the remaining elements.

My usual version of this uses `n` instead of `2 * n`.  The change is to allow your final group to be longer than the rest.  I usually want it to be shorter.  (1-20, 21-40, 41-60, 61-65.)  I prefer `[[...xs]]` to just `[xs]` because this way there's no chance of mutating the original by mutating the returned array or vice versa.  But that may not be a concern for you.

Comment: Thank you so much, Scott! Yeah, you're right, exactly what I need!